# Issue w/ get.Range() of null

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble with the following code where I keep getting an error message

> Cannot read property 'getRange' of null.

The error message appears when executing the code line:

```
var vs=dbsh.getRange(2,1,dbsh.getLastRow()-1,25).getValues();
```

Can anyone help on this issue?

```
function M*******o() {
 Run_M*****9();
 Run_2****C();
 Run_M****0();
 AddForm();
}

  
function Run_M*****9() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("File ID"); /* Final Consolidation File */
  const sk = ss.getSheetByName('Config'); /* Access worksheet CONFIG */
  var cc = sk.getRange("D5").getValue();  /* Access file ID in worksheet CONFIG */
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Manual'); /* Destination worksheet in final consolidation file */
  sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(),30).clearContent(); /* Clear content in the Destination WS */
  var dbss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(cc); /* Access origin using range in var cc*/
  const dbsh=dbss.getSheetByName('Database'); /* Access origin WS */
  var vs=dbsh.getRange(2,1,dbsh.getLastRow()-1,25).getValues(); /* Paste Values */
  var ff=sh.getRange(2,1,dbsh.getLastRow()-1,25).setValues(vs);   
}  

function R*****C() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(""File ID""); /* Final Consolidation File */
  const sk = ss.getSheetByName('Config'); /* Access worksheet CONFIG */
  var cc = sk.getRange("D7").getValue();  /* Access range in worksheet CONFIG */
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Manual'); /* Destination worksheet in final consolidation file */
  var dbss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(cc); /* Access origin using range in var cc*/
  const dbsh=dbss.getSheetByName('Database'); /* Access origin WS */
  var vs=dbsh.getRange(2,1,dbsh.getLastRow()-1,25).getValues(); /* Paste Values */
  var ff=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,dbsh.getLastRow()-1,25).setValues(vs); 
}  

function R********0() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("File ID"); /* Final Consolidation File */
  const sk = ss.getSheetByName('Config'); /* Access worksheet CONFIG */
  var cc = sk.getRange("D6").getValue();  /* Access range in worksheet CONFIG */
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Manual'); /* Destination worksheet in final consolidation file */
  var dbss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(cc); /* Access origin using range in var cc*/
  const dbsh=dbss.getSheetByName('Database'); /* Access origin WS */
  var vs=dbsh.getRange(2,1,dbsh.getLastRow()-1,25).getValues(); /* Paste Values */
  var ff=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,dbsh.getLastRow()-1,25).setValues(vs); 
}
```

Comment: Can you do a `Logger.log(dbsh)` after you access the origin WS and post the result from the logs? Also, any reason why you declare it as `const`?

Comment: Hello. Here are the logs. [20-09-29 15:11:31:178 BST] Sheet (Log run for dbsh)   +   
[20-09-29 15:11:35:829 BST] TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
    at Run_2019SC(Code:45:15)
    at ManualSGAConso(Code:3:2)

Comment: I declare as "const" because it's what I usually do to get sheet name

Comment: Can you now `Logger.log(dbsh.getSheetName())`? Just to make sure! Also if you could update the question with these logs not put them in the comments, that would be great. Another thing to make sure is that your appscript.json has the proper scope for using [`openById`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) though if the previous log returns a sheet...it is strange

Comment: Closed as duplicate. There are no other reasons except that the sheet with that name "Database" doesn't exist. Check for spaces, case, non printable characters or just rename that sheet to something simpler like `S1`

Comment: @iansedano Looking again, The difference in logs could be explained if OP added the logger in function `Run_M*****9`, while the error is thrown at `Run_2019SC`. There is a sheet named "Database" in spreadsheet with id = D5's value, but not in the spreadsheet with id=D7's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `dbss.getSheetByName('Database')` retunrs `null`, meaning: the `dbss` hasn't a sheet named `Database`.

Verify that your code is getting the correct spreadsheet and that it has a sheet named  `Database`. Please bear in mind that `getSheetByName` is case sensitive.

Comment: Hello Ruben. Thank you for your support. But the sheet 'Database' exists in the file. It must be something else, but I just can't figure it out. It actually stopped working when I replaced the "var cc = sk.getRange("D5").getValue()" to retrieve the file URL instead of using the URL (ID) directly on the code, if that helps.

Comment: @user13332855 URL and ID aren't the same, you should use the appropiate value or change your code accordingly. If you need further help, please edit the question to include enough details to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added the entire code. I'm using the file ID. For function Run_M*****9() everything runs smoothly. For function R*****C() I get the previously mentioned error message.

Comment: @user13332855 We don't need the entire code, we need a [mcve]. If your code depends on spreadsheets, you should include on the question the minimal but complete spreadsheet details that are relevant to reproduce the problem.